# Sql Server 2008 Selecting Distinct

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble filtering out duplicate column values.

Here's my results, thus far:

```
ProjectNumber, WorkOrder, Shipment, Start, End, Quantity, PartName
------------------------------------------------------------------
1234 | 1234-01 | S-01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 200 | Part A
1234 | 1234-02 | S-01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 200 | Part B
1234 | 1234-03 | S-01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 200 | Part C
2345 | 2345-01 | S-01 | 2015-09-02 00:00:01 | 2015-09-02 00:00:01 | 12  | Part A
2345 | 2345-02 | S-01 | 2015-09-02 00:00:01 | 2015-09-02 00:00:01 | 24  | Part B
```

I know I need to group by ProjectNumber, with the first WorkOrder's data, if that makes sense. So the desired result would be:

```
ProjectNumber, WorkOrder, Shipment, Start, End, Quantity, PartName
------------------------------------------------------------------
1234 | 1234-01 | S-01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 2015-09-01 00:00:01 | 200 | Part A
2345 | 2345-01 | S-01 | 2015-09-02 00:00:01 | 2015-09-02 00:00:01 | 12  | Part A
```

What I've tried thus far, with no dice.

```
SELECT
  ProjectNumber, ProductionNotes AS Shipment, PromiseDate AS "End", Notes, 
  MIN(WorkOrderNumber) AS "Work Order", Name AS "Sales Order", PromiseDate, 
  Quantity, PartName
FROM Database.dbo.daWorkOrders
WHERE StatusTypeID = 3
GROUP BY ProjectNumber
ORDER BY PromiseDate ASC;
```

Response:

> Column 'Database.dbo.daWorkOrders.ProductionNotes' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what this error is saying is that if you are going to use the `GROUP BY` clause, then your result is going to be a relation/table with a row for each group, so in your `SELECT` statement you can only "select" the column that you are grouping by and use aggregate functions on that column because the other columns will not appear in the resulting table.

Please try to use this query:

```
SELECT ProjectNumber
,      ProductionNotes AS Shipment
,      PromiseDate AS "End"
,      Notes
,      MIN(WorkOrderNumber) AS "Work Order"
,      Name AS "Sales Order"
,      PromiseDate
,      Quantity
,      PartName
FROM   Database.dbo.daWorkOrders
WHERE  StatusTypeID = 3
GROUP BY ProjectNumber, ProductionNotes, PromiseDate, Note, Name, PromiseDate, Quantity, PartName
ORDER BY PromiseDate ASC;
```

Comment: I get this repsonse: `The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.`

Comment: Makes sense. I'll just remove the excess rows programatically. Thanks

Comment: @MegaTron This query wouldn't produce the desired result since you are grouping on PartName and Quantity...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `row_number()` window function with a partitioning clause: `over (partition by [ProjectNumber] order by [WorkOrderNumber])` and filter for row number = 1 in each partition:

```
with cte as (
    select 
       rn = row_number() over (partition by [ProjectNumber] order by [WorkOrderNumber])
       , *
    from Database.dbo.daWorkOrders
)
select * from cte
where rn = 1;
```

This would give you the first WorkOrder for each ProjectNumber:

```
rn  ProjectNumber   WorkOrder   Shipment    Start   End Quantity    PartName
1   1234    1234-01 S-01    2015-09-01 00:00:01 2015-09-01 00:00:01 200 Part A
1   2345    2345-01 S-01    2015-09-02 00:00:01 2015-09-02 00:00:01 12  Part A
```

If your WorkOrder column is of `text` type you can cast it to a varchar to get the partition to work:

```
row_number() over (partition by [ProjectNumber] order by cast([WorkOrder] as varchar(20)))
```

(20 might not be the right size, adjust as needed).